# How to remove non-numeric from a string but retain decimal in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium(C#) on NUnit Framework and is getting a string from UI as **$4850.19**. 
I want to compare above string with the value from backend (DB) to assert they are equal. 
I am using a below method to parse my dollar amount from front-end, but the issue is that is also stripping the decimal point; and obviously the comparison with backend is failing.

Method used:

```
 public static string RemoveNonNumeric(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            if (Char.IsNumber(s[i]))
                sb.Append(s[i]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

How to strip out any '$' or ',' but keep '.' in the value?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as `return s.Replace("$", String.Empty)` ?

Comment: Or possibly `return s.Substring(1);`?

Comment: Those methods won't remove the `','` character, though...

Answer (score 9):

With Reg ex it's trivial

```
Regex.Replace(s, "[^0-9.]", "")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `decimal.Parse` method to parse a `string` formatted as currency into a `decimal` type:

```
string input = "$4,850.19";
decimal result = decimal.Parse(input, NumberStyles.Currency);

Console.WriteLine($"{input} => {result}");
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it if you don't want to go the `decimal.Parse` route is to simply return only numeric and `'.'` characters from the string:

```
public static string RemoveNonNumeric2(string s)
{
    return string.Concat(s?.Where(c => char.IsNumber(c) || c == '.') ?? "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all inputs above, I kind of figured out an easy way to handle this for now (as shown below) -

```
public static string RemoveNonNumeric(string s)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            if (Char.IsNumber(s[i]) || s[i] == '.')
                sb.Append(s[i]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I would like to try other ways of handling this as well soon.